# Chat feature in mobile app

Tags: angularjs, chat, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a ionic mobile app for android and ios. There is this requirement to have a feature where two people can chat in this app.

Are there any existing free/paid API's that can be easily integrated with my application to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a demo app that does exactly that:
https://github.com/firebase/firechat